# Страница с вкладками swift

Tags: swift

Добрый день. Необходимо сделать страницу, вверху должны быть вкладки. Они должны двигаться как в `UIScrollView` так как их может быть много.
Ниже вкладок таблица. При нажатии на вкладку, информация в таблице должна меняться. Таблицу так же можно было бы пролистнуть и попасть на соседнюю вкладку. Не знаю понятно ли описал. Думал модно в `UIScrollView` добавить как и картинки через `AddSubView()`, но название говорит за себя, так не получается.
Я предполагал так, что есть массив с вкладками, при загрузке Контроллера они создаются. Какие могут быть варианты?

Comment: Мне подходит предложенная вещь, единственное вместо ViewController нужен TableViewController. Класс то я поменял. Но как заполнить ячейки, предположим из массива. Нашел вот такую штуку https://github.com/awseeley/Custom-Table-Cell но скрестить не сумел.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [это](https://github.com/cemolcay/SlidingContainerViewController) готовое решение [с GitHub](https://github.com/cemolcay/SlidingContainerViewController)

Полностью подходит под Ваше описание.
Установка и настройка описана в Readme

Comment: Спасибо огромное. То что надо. Попробую разобраться.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал Cocoa Pod XLPagerTabStrip: [github](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip)

Он обновляется и поддерживается автором pod'а.